# Why does it keep giving me break outside loop?

Tags: syntax-error, break

extra = int(input("Would you like to purchase something else? (yes or no)"))
if extra == "yes":
pass
elif extra == "no":
break
else:
continue

Answer (score 1):

When I run the code posted, it sees 'syntax error' at the ':' -- because it is.  There are multiple other errors.  I suspect that you want something like

```
while True:
    extra = int(input("Would you like to purchase something else? (yes or no)"))
    if extra == "yes":
        pass
    elif extra == "no":
        break
    else: continue
    <code to purchase something else>
```

Perhaps you need to read the tutorial or parts of the reference manual some more.